# DateTime::createFromFormat Returns False - Milliseconds

Tags: php

I am a bit confused why the following fails. I have a datetime string in the format of

`YmdHisv`

lets say the string = `20201212000000000`

Why would the following fail (ignore the odd input)?

```
$year = date("Y");
$input = ($year."1212"."00000000"."0");
$format = "YmdHisv";

$stamp = DateTime::createFromFormat($format,$input);
```

The errors returned with this are:

```
  'error_count' => int 2
  'errors' => 
    array (size=2)
      14 => string 'The format separator does not match' (length=35)
      15 => string 'Trailing data' (length=13)
```

If I remove my milliseconds there is no issue.

Edit: Doing the following returns a 3 digit millisecond time. So not sure why *my* milliseconds are invalid.

```
$now = new DateTime();
echo $now->format("v");
```

Edit: looks like the following will also fail. There is [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) of weird behavior with `u` (microseconds) but what about `v` (miliseconds)?

```
$format = "YmdHisv";
$now = new DateTime();
$now = $now->format($format);
$stamp = DateTime::createFromFormat($format,$now);
```

Edit: I may have my answer but looking for more explanation [from documentation]

> - The createFromFormat DOES NOT accept the ".v" modifier, unlike the formatting ones.

Comment: Feel free to answer to own question if you found the answer in the documentation.

Comment: @pintxo I likely will but am holding out for a more complete explanation than is provided on the comments of the docs

Comment: From the docs: "7.3.0 The v format specifier has been added."  Maybe your php version is too old?

Comment: @pintxo I think you are correct because I am on a slightly older version. I will update and share results. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer thanks to @pintxo. My PHP version needed to be updated.

> Pre 7.3+ : The createFromFormat DOES NOT accept the ".v" modifier, unlike the
> formatting ones.

> 7.3.0 The v format specifier has been added.